# Assign port number dynamically in a range of values

Tags: c++, sockets, port

I am trying to dynamically assign a port number to a client and so I have implemented the following method inside the connection class:

```
void TCPConnection::bindSocket() {
  short result;
  clieParams.sin_family = AF_INET;
  for (unsigned short port = MIN_PORT_NUMBER; port < MAX_PORT_NUMBER; port++) {
    clieParams.sin_port = htons(port);
    result = bind(socketFD, (const struct sockaddr*) &clieParams, sizeof clieParams);
    printf("%i\t", result);
    if (!(result < 0)) {
#ifdef DEBUG
      std::cout << "[DEBUG] Socket bound with port " << port << "..." << std::endl;
#endif
      break;
    }
  }
  if (result < 0) {
    throw TCPConnectionException("Socket bind failed.");
  }
```

Launching that class on different processes, the above method always binds the socket on the same port, despite it is already assigned to and used by other processes (the `connect()` function called inside another method returns error). Due to this I'm going to ask you:

1. Is this a normal behaviour of the `bind()` function?
2. If yes, this happens because sockets are related to processes only (using other words, each process has its own sockets) while ports are network interface related?
3. If yes, how can I dynamically assign port values inside a range without creating conflicts with other processes?
4. Is the assignment of `0` to `clieParams.sin_port` the only available solution to this problem?

Comment: Can you explain, at a high level, what you're trying to accomplish here? Do you want to run multiple copies of your server, each claiming a port number for itself, or do you want multiple clients to connect to the same server, or what exactly?

Comment: The listed code is a method of a class that represents a single TCP connection. On the other side I am implementing a multithread server able to manage more connections at the same time. In order to test it, I instantiate this class in `main()` and I launch several copies of the same process. This method should make tests easier, because it should be able to find an available port automatically, instead of let the user define it manually.

Comment: @rudicangiotti But why are you `bind()`'ing the clients at all? If you don't call `bind()` at all, or at least if you `bind()` to port 0, then `connect()` will implicitly bind an **available random port** for you. You don't need to `bind()` a client unless a protocol or a firewall requires specific ports. But, to answer your question, on some platforms (you didn't mention which you are using), it is possible to `bind()` a client to a port that is already in use without error from `bind()` since the requested port is not actually used until `connect()`, when it will then fail.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, well, I bind also the client in order to have a more granular control over the network. Anyway, if these are the side-effects of binding client too and there are not simple solutions to the issue, I will revert to not bound clients. I am running all this on macOS Sierra.

Comment: There is no need for this kind of 'granular control over the network'. Uninformed net admins sometimes think it's clever to restrict outbound ports for certain applications to a specific range. It isn't. There is no security benefit and no other benefit either. All it does is make applications impossible to write, as you are discovering.

Comment: So, it is not a good practice to explicitly bind a client (`bind()` should not be called, or anyway could be called but with a port number set to `0`). What about server, on the other side? Also server should/could not bind sockets to an explicitly defined port?

Comment: "Also server should/could not bind sockets to an explicitly defined port?" You can try and see what happens. Where would your clients connect to?

Comment: As others have said, it is *generally* unnecessary explicitly bind client-side sockets. Expanding a bit on @RemyLebeau's comment, the 5-tuple `<protocol, local_ip, local_port, remote_ip, remote_port>` uniquely identifies a "connection". For client-side TCP sockets this 5-tuple is fully defined after `connect()` completes. One could, in theory, do what you are attempting by including the `connect()` call in the retry loop logic, but it's not worth the hassle.

Comment: @n.m. yes, my question is a bit silly and not well formulated. Of course there must be at least a bound port on server: by knowing it, clients can successfully connect to server. However, considering a server-client configuration where these latter establish a TCP connection to a known server port in order to get UDP parameters to start a parallel UDP connection, should server explicitly bind a chosen port or could it be better to set port to `0` and then use `getsockname()`, in order to get the system chosen port and send it to client?

Comment: @RemyLebeau when you wrote: *"on some platforms [...], it is possible to bind() a client to a port that is already in use without error from bind() since the requested port is not actually used until connect(), when it will then fail"* did you mean that also if `netstat` report an `established` connection on that IP and port, `bind()` can not return error?

Comment: @rudicangiotti that is platform-specific behavior. The bind may succeed or fail. And, to follow up on user207421's comment, it can be useful to bind a client to a specific network interface, in cases where the client machine is connected to multiple networks, but it is rarely if ever useful to bind a client to a specific port unless you are required to by external restrictions.

Comment: What you say is possible and in fact some system work in a similar fashion, like ONC (Sun) RPC for example.